# UPDATE TABLE T1 SET COLUMN= SELECT 0 FROM TABLE T1

Tags: oracle

```
UPDATE SCPOMGR.DFUVIEW D
     SET D.UDC_NEWDFU  =  (SELECT (CASE WHEN D1.UDC_CREATIONDATE > ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC(SYSDATE),3)
                              THEN 1
                              ELSE 0
                                  END)
                           FROM SCPOMGR.DFUVIEW D1, SCPOMGR.UDT_GEN_PARAM G
                         WHERE D.DMDUNIT = D1.DMDUNIT
                           AND D.DMDGROUP = D1.DMDGROUP
                           AND D.LOC = D1.LOC 
                           AND G.REGION=VREGION
                           AND G.JDA_CODE=SUBSTR(D1.DMDUNIT,-2,2)
                           );
```

WHAT WILL A SELECT 0 DO?
WILL IT SELECT NO ROWS AND UPDATE THE COLUMN WITH A NULL?

Comment: `NULL`  is different from 0.

Comment: Can you explain what the select statement is actually doing.
Because i am getting an alert saying that udc_newdfu cannot be set to null.

Comment: Please tag correctly. Is a oracle or mysql question?? Don´t use all tags that you see

Comment: @KaushikNayak , i had already checked on this, but that's  not the case.Neither is udc_creation date null anywhere and also, the where condition is fetching rows.

Comment: The SELECT 0 gets a row with 0 value for each row that matches the rest of conditions, so if you have 10 rows that match the WHERE and so on you will get 10 rows with 0 value. In this case, if they match the CASE statement, you will get 1 value instead of 0

Comment: That is strange.There is some information which appears to be missing .can you also append the complete error message to your question?

Comment: @nacho agreed, it will fetch 10 rows with 0 as column values. now,what will the update statement get updated with?
 update scpomgr.dfuview d 
             set udc_newdfu=select 0 from ..,..  where.. and...

Comment: UDP_DP_D_11_DEMAND_UDCS_CALC.fboolCalcUDC_Weekly_Sunday: Unexpected ORACLE Error. Sqlerrm: ORA-01407: cannot update ("SCPOMGR"."DFUVIEW"."UDC_NEWDFU") to NULL 30-AUG-17 11.29.57.124651000 AM
@KaushikNayak Please check the exact alert i am getting.

Comment: @Mathguy.with due respect , could u please delete your comment as it is disrespectful. There are times when people err but  I wish not  to involve in a verbal and personal battle .

Comment: @KaushikNayak - sure; I was going to, but apparently Big Brother beat me to it. I don't see it anymore, someone else deleted it already. Also: please note the period in your last comment, right after my nickname; this made the whole reference be `@Mathguy.with`, so I wasn't alerted to your comment, I only saw it now...

Answer (score 0):

On the right-hand side of the assignment (the value you want to UPDATE) you have a SELECT statement with a CASE expression. There is a subquery (a join with several additional filters). The SELECT statement will return exactly as many rows as there are in the join and satisfy all the additional filters. For some of those rows the SELECT statement will return 1 and for the others, 0.

Do you expect that the subquery (the join with many WHERE conditions) will return exactly one row, then you check the CREATIONDATE and based on that, you update the value to 1 or 0?

In principle, the SELECT statement may return more than one row - in which case you will get a different error message, something about a scalar query (one that is **supposed** to be scalar, anyway) returning more than one row.

It is also possible that the subquery returns no rows at all - in that case the SELECT statement will return no rows at all, and in such cases the UPDATE means "assign NULL to the column of the left-hand side of the assignment". This is what seems to have happened here.

That is no reason to raise an exception. However, you would get an exception if the column (UDC_NEWDFU) has a NOT NULL constraint.

Since the CASE expression can ONLY return 0 or 1, never NULL, the ONLY way where a NULL assignment is possible is when the subquery (the join with many conditions) returns no rows. In one of the Comments you said that subquery does return rows. I don't believe you. If it does return rows, then I don't believe you that you have an update to NULL being attempted.

Comment: Hi @mathguy, thank you for explaining it so well. I am glad, my understanding matched what you have suggested. I, in fact, could not think of any possible reason than the ones you stated above. The select is for sure returning rows, around 20k. udc_newdfu has a not null constraint.

Comment: @sahibathakral - the subquery is **correlated**, which means: it selects rows from the join of `D1` and `G` (using your aliases) that match each successive row of `D` on the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. So, for each row of `D`, the result set may be different, and for **some** rows in `D`, the result may be empty (no rows). So, to say that "the select returns around 20k rows" doesn't make sense - there isn't one select statement, there are as many as there are rows in `D`. Perhaps the statement returns 20k rows for some rows of `D`, but perhaps not for all of them!

Comment: ,I really appreciate your in depth knowledge on the matter.I have a question, in the case when result may be empty, ie no row, will it then update to null? 
The 20k is the number of relevant rows in scpomgr.dfuview. 
As per my understanding, table D is getting updated on every successful join of D1 and G.Is my understanding right?

Also, in this scenario, the udc_creationdate is never greater than sysdate +3 months, despite that , udc_newdfu is taking 1 as the value.
I can't figure out what's wrong